# Transform javascript object from one form to another

Tags: javascript, mapreduce

Input

```
const products = {
      100: ['abc', 'xyz', 'mno', 'pqr'],
      200: ['mno', 'pqr'],
      300: ['abc', 'xyz'],
      400: ['abc', 'pqr'],
    }
```

Expected

```
{
abc: [100, 300, 400],
xyz: [100, 300],
mno: [100, 200],
pqr: [100, 400]
}
```

My solution:

```
var results = {};
Object.keys(products).forEach(function(id){
console.log(id)
products[id].forEach(function(user){
   if(typeof results[user] === 'undefined'){
     results[user] = [];
   }
   results[user].push(id)
  })
})
console.log(results)
```

is there a better way to do this, like map, reduce..etc??

Comment: Your approach looks fine for me. You could trim it down a bit with arrow functions and `Object.entries` and `if(!results[user])` but the general approach is just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is fine, I'd provide another map/reduce example as you request.

```js
const products = {
  100: ['abc', 'xyz', 'mno', 'pqr'],
  200: ['mno', 'pqr'],
  300: ['abc', 'xyz'],
  400: ['abc', 'pqr'],
}

let result = Object.entries(products)
  .flatMap(([id,tokens])=>tokens.map(token=>({token,id})))
  .reduce((index,{token,id})=>{
    if(index[token]) index[token].push(id) 
    else index[token] = [id]
    return index
   },{})
 
console.log(result)
```

Comment: whic one has better time and space complexity?

Comment: @user1614862 since in `javascript` map create a new array (instead of some kind of iterator) this map-reduce would cause more memory and time. But the point of map/reduce is usually not time/memory complexity anyway.

Comment: @user1614862 btw, I personally think `reduce` should return a new object instead of modify existing one (although It's totally fine), I'd use a loop (or forEach) for this case.

Answer (score 1):

here it is with Array Reduce

```js
const products= 
        { 100: [ 'abc', 'xyz', 'mno', 'pqr'] 
        , 200: [ 'mno', 'pqr'] 
        , 300: [ 'abc', 'xyz'] 
        , 400: [ 'abc', 'pqr'] 
        } 

var result= Object.keys(products).reduce((acc, elm)=>
              {
              for (let ref of products[elm]) 
                {
                if (!acc[ref]) acc[ref]= [Number(elm)]
                else           acc[ref].push(Number(elm))
                }
              return acc
              }
              ,{})

for (trace in result) console.log(trace, ':', JSON.stringify(result[trace]))
```

the same with a double reduce as **@Bergi** asked in his comment:

```js
const products= 
        { 100: [ 'abc', 'xyz', 'mno', 'pqr'] 
        , 200: [ 'mno', 'pqr'] 
        , 300: [ 'abc', 'xyz'] 
        , 400: [ 'abc', 'pqr'] 
        } 

var result = Object.keys(products).reduce((acc, elm) =>
              products[elm].reduce((acc, ref) =>
                {
                if (!acc[ref]) acc[ref]= [Number(elm)]
                else           acc[ref].push(Number(elm))
                return acc
                }
                , acc)
              , {})

for (trace in result) console.log(trace, ':', JSON.stringify(result[trace]))
```

Comment: I would recommend not to mix `reduce` with `for` loops though. Stay consistent.

Comment: @bergi there is an array inside, how did you want to loop thru in other way ?

Comment: With `reduce`, again, if you did the outer loop with `reduce`.

Comment: @Bergi I did it, but I'm not really convinced if it's really a plus

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant - see my edit suggestion :-) Feel free to roll it back if you don't like it